# Get all photos added to the facebook feed using GraphAPI

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this request to get all the feeds of the public facebook page.

```
GraphRequestAsyncTask graphRequestAsyncTask = new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "//" + pageId + "/posts/",
            null,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                    if (jsonObject == null) {
                        return;
                    }                       
                }
            }
    ).executeAsync();
```

And the response contains the **picture** tag which contains the url which denotes the only one image, But how to get all the images contains in that feed. Is there any tag(field) to get the all images

Comment: If you're trying to get photos posted by the page, you can query `/photos` instead of  `/posts`

Comment: I want to get the photos attached to the particular post

Comment: Try `/[post-id]/attachments`. You'd first have to call `/posts` to get the post IDs, then query the attachments as it's not possible to get the attachments for multiple posts at once.

Comment: But some times it was not giving all the photos. It was gicing only one.